# jQuery form validation with available email check

Tags: validation, jquery, email-validation

So I have a form that uses the jQuery validation plugin to check the fields before the form can be submitted... pretty basic stuff and that all works fine but I would like the email to also be checked against the database for duplicates.

If one is found then I dont want the form to be submitted obviously and have an error display next to the field. I have tried a couple of things but nothing has worked. Here is my code that validates all the fields.

```
$(function(){
    $('#myform')
       .validate({
         submitHandler: function(form) {

           $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                success: function() {
                    $('#myForm').append("<p class='thanks'>Thanks!</p>")
                }
           });
         }
      }); 
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

User the [`remote`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/Methods/remote#options) method of validation:

```
$(function() {
    $('#myform').validate({
        rules: {
            email: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                remote: "check-email.php"
            }
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {

            $(form).ajaxSubmit({
                success: function() {
                    $('#myForm').append("<p class='thanks'>Thanks!</p>")
                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks this is exactly what i was looking for, however how do I handle the call back, in my php script do i just make my function return true if a user name is taken and false if it isnt?

Comment: nevermind i figured it out! thanks for your input it really helped me out